# How to insert current date/time in the content of a post?

Tags: posts, date-time

I'm making a [list of suggestion here](http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/my-suggestions-for-visual-studio-2010/). I need to insert current date/time for each of my suggestions - they are added accumulatively.

If you have any idea on doing that, please share.

Comment: Gi Vu: Do you do this via the regular post editor, or via the API? Because I thought both default to the current date and time if you don't specify it?

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Via regular editor. The date/time I need is in the post content not of the post itself.

Comment: Gi Vu: What if you would insert something like `[curdate]` in your post, and replace this in [the `content_save_pre` hook](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/content_save_pre) with the current date and time? Because you do it before you save it to the database, it won't be updated the next time (because `[curdate]` will be gone).

Comment: Gi Vu: Nevermind, I did not notice you were on WordPress.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on WordPress.com, so there's no way to add functionality that will allow you to do this. You could always type the date/time manually whenever you update it.